# Does the 'too' meaning have 'limited extent'?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

I have been curious about 'too' meaning.

In this sentence "You cannot be too careful.", does 'too' have the meaning of 'limited extent'?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, "too" means "excessively".

No matter how careful you are, it's not more careful than you should be.

Answer (score 1):

> You can never be too careful
>   *you can always be more careful than you are now*

has the meaning one can never be overly cautious, just as

> You can never be too rich*
>   *you can always want more money*

"too" has the meaning of "too much" or "overly".

*I refrain from citing the other half of this usual idiomatic phrase